# Why horizontal scrollbar appears?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

My site is made of sections that have those styles:

```
.site-section{
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

When I open the site, a horizontal scrollbar appears. I hid it by `::-webkit-scrollbar {display: none;}`, but it isn't a good solution because not all browsers support it. Do you know why this problem happens?

Comment: Is there more than 1 section in each page? If the page has more then 100vh height it will show a scroll bar. It could be the default margin on `<body>` or any other reason. You can right-click on your page and "Inspect" it to highlight the surface of each container to better understand where everything is placed and what is causing the additional height.

Comment: @leuquim, the scrollbar is caused because the body and html tags have margins and paddings.

Answer (score 1):

The horizontal scroll bar is caused by your CSS: `width: 100vw;`.

To remove it place the declaration `overflow-x: hidden;` on your body tag.

Answer (score 1):

You horizontal scrollbar is caused because your `site-section` has a width of 100vw. The browser is fine with that but it also accounts for margin and padding (blue and red).

[image: margin and padding]

This results in an overflow and thus the browser adds a horizontal scrollbar (along with a vertical one);

The best way to fix this is to use [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()).

```css
.site-section{
  background-color: lightblue; /* I added this so you can see the new extents of the .site-section */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  width: calc(100vw - 16px);
  height: calc(100vh - 16px);
}
```

```html
<div class = 'site-section'>
  Hello world
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of the context of your code, the most likely explanation is that you've left the browser to use its default settings and these could include margin and padding.

If this is so, then even if you only have this element as the first one, either it, or body, or both etc. will make your element shift a bit and with width 100vw this means it will be just too wide and/or high for the viewport, hence the scrollbars appearing.

Put this at the top of your CSS and see if it makes a difference in your particular scenario:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```